Подключение базы данных к сайту, написанному на JavaScript
Логика моего сайта написана на JavaScript. Я хочу прикрутить к сайту систему авторизации, раскидать файл .js на несколько модулей (насколько я понимаю, это скроет содержащийся в подгружаемых модулях код от просмотра пользователями) и добавить возможность работы с базой данных (как минимум, вывод на одну из страниц рейтинга авторизованных пользователей).
Какие инструменты мне для этого понадобятся? Например, использовать ли nodeJS или ASP.Net Web Api?
Я только приступаю к изучению серверной части сайта и, не будучи профессиональным программистом, боюсь зря потратить время, упорно копая не в ту сторону.

«это скроет содержащийся в подгружаемых модулях» — нет, пользователю абсолютно ничего не мешает посмотреть, что, где и зачем подгружается

На самом деле всё зависит от уровня ваших знаний, если в фронтенде вы используете какие-то популярные фреймворки по типу Vue/React/Angular, то в них есть вспомогательные решения с удобной разработкой сразу и бэкенд части. Если этого нет, то вам нужен классический бэкенд и отправка запросов с фронтенда. Проще всего выбрать какой-то готовый стэк, обычно там уже настроены минимальные для работы вещи, такие как авторизация, валидация форм и удобный API для взаимодействия. Вы упомянули .Net и как раз там есть Blazor
